# Safely unwrapping optional with guard let in init()

Tags: swift, function, option-type, init, guard

I think I probably missed the point of how this works but I have a class that needs to use a global optional value in several of its methods and right now I unwrapped it inside every method but I thought I could just unwrap the value in init(). Am I doing it wrong or is this now how it's supposed to work? - Thank you.

```
let iCloudPath = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")


class iCloudManager {

    init() {
        guard let iCloudPath = iCloudPath else { return }
    }

    function1(){
        // uses iCloudPath but returns 'Value of optional type 'URL?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'URL''
    }

    function2(){
        // uses iCloudPath but returns 'Value of optional type 'URL?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'URL''
    }

}
```

Comment: What does a return value of `nil` mean here, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the result as a property of your objects. Better yet, use a static property, not a global.

```
class iCloudManager {
    static let defaultPath = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")

    let path: URL

    init?() {
        guard let path = iCloudManager.defaultPath else { return nil }
        self.path = path
    }

    func function1() {
        // uses self.path
    }

    func function2() {
        // uses self.path
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Alexander, thanks for answering another one of my questions. Would you be willing to tell me a bit more about how that works? Wouldn’t return nil crash the application if the value is nil? To answer your comment, it would be nil if for some reason the iCloud container or the documents folder don’t exist. I do have checks to see if iCloud is enabled on the device and a way to create the documents folder if it doesn’t exist in the container, but you never know.

Comment: @CristianMoisei It's an optional initializer, note the `init?`. So if you do `let foo = iCloudManager()` and the path is nil, then `foo` will be nil.

Comment: "Wouldn’t return nil crash the application if the value is nil?" Nope. This is called a "failable initializer". It returns a `iCloudManager?`, rather than the usual `iCloudManager`. It'll crash on `nil` only if you tell it to crash on `nil` (by force unwrapping with `!`.